# Foreman not finding rake tasks; error: rake tasks 'not found'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jruby, foreman

Using Foreman on my rails application with Ruby 1.9.3 just fine. Switched to JRuby and now, as an example, get :

```
18:22:16 solr.1 | /home/scott/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.8@jruby168-unicon/gems/foreman-0.47.0/bin/foreman-runner: 32: exec: bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:run: not found
```

When I run `bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:run` on its own on the command line it runs just fine

**Procfile:**

```
web: puma
solr: bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:run
redis: redis-server ./config/redis.conf
sidekiq: bundle exec sidekiq -c $SIDEKIQ_CONCURRENCY -q report -q publish_item -q audio -q import -q email -q enrollment -q bugsnag
bunchball: bundle exec sidekiq -c 2 -q bunchball
sidekiq_solr: bundle exec sidekiq -c 1 -q solr
```

Answer (score 1):

You have install `bundler` in Jruby.

```
gem install bundler
```

Comment: Well smack me in the head. Thanks!

Comment: Okay this is weird... after the first time running it (and not getting the not found errors) the command is back to giving the error